# CloudFront very slow TTFB after enabling HTTP/2

Tags: dns, https, cdn, optimization, amazon-cloudfront

My site was running on HTTP/1.1 with CloudFront at front, Webpagetest reports the load time usually at 2 seconds. Yesterday I enabled HTTP/2 (and SSL) on CloudFront, hoping to see an improvement. The result is, however, it becomes slower.

The load time is now around 3 seconds (have tested with different locations). The Waterfall View shows most assets receive a big increase on TTFB comparing with HTTP/1.1. For example, a 3KB image had **250ms** TTFB before, with HTTP/2, it's now **750ms**.

Did I miss something simple?

---

Here are Webpagetest reports, if it helps

HTTP/1.1 https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180518_QY_4ecdf2626af50c5451dedddfbed2aef4/3/details/#waterfall_view_step1

HTTP/2 https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180519_TQ_cb737ae6e67b06da503d34d8d17d2e3a/3/details/#waterfall_view_step1

Comment: I think you would need to use HTTPS on your HTTP/1.1 test for this to be a fair comparison.

Comment: The purple bar on the HTTPS version for the "SSL" stuff only added 100ms to the exchange. What significantly changed is the blue bar, labeled HTML, it almost tripled. As a generic advice I would also try not to derive big conclusions with only a single test. Did you try other tests too?